# Flow is undefined - class inheritance issue? (Ruby Shoes)

Tags: ruby, shoes-4

I am following a sample located [here](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/blob/master/samples/class-book.rb) in the samples folder on the official Shoes github repo. I saw that the programmer defined a class `Book` which inherited from `Shoes`. I have a relatively large program coming along with shoes that I'm porting for 3.x, and I wanted to split all of my different classes into smaller files to make it easier on me. I have a file like so

```
#this class essentially sets up user interface
class Interface < Shoes
  def initialize
    flow do
      @shed = button "New"
      @editbutton = button "Edit"
      @employees = button "Employees"
      @sdays = button "Special Days"
      @makenote = button "Make Note"
      @backbutton = button "Go Back"
    end
  end
end
```

My main file looks like so

```
$LOAD_PATH << "."
require 'loader' #all of these are other classes i have defined
require 'interface' #contains the interface class
require 'schutil'
Shoes.app title: "Baesler's Scheduling Application", width: 1024, height: 768, resizable: true do
  Interface.new
end
```

First of all, in the sample I provided, the programmer never had to use a block with Shoes.app. I don't know how, but his class got initialized with shoes when it was ran. That was my original intention, but when I try that (the code above without ever calling Interface.init), nothing shows up in Shoes, but it does load. However, using the above code as-is, I get the following error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'flow' for nil:NilClass`

If it helps at all, I am using the Shoes 4 preview 3 gem and am running Windows 8.1 64 bit. What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug in the Shoes codebase, or am I doing this wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the initialize method which breaks the whole setup of shoes (it needs to get an app instance on which to call the flow method for instance).

You are also following a `url` sample without using any actual `url` calls.

A [widget](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/blob/1b86197e86eabfcdcf804d867c909716cc8bc59f/samples/simple-guess-game.rb) might suit your use case better.

Personally I rather resort to defining methods within an app and then calling those :)